# Distance between two distribution of image

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, mathematics-education

I am looking for a common distance method to compare two distribution (ex: histogram of image). Please suggest to me some common method to do it. I found some method ex: Bhattacharyya distance , K-L distance. Do you have other?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103115/distance-metric-between-two-sample-distributions-histograms

Comment: try earthmover distance:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance

Comment: @AryehKontorovich: It is very good answer. Thank you so much. I have read it. But it already published in some paper. So i need find other solution. Do you know other solution for this problem. Some papers that I found as http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6116341 and http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6587483&queryText%3DLinearized+Multidimensional+Earth-Mover%E2%80%99s-Distance+Gradient+Flows

Answer (score 1):

NID,normalized information distance which is motivated by Kolmogorov complexity ,please see papers of Ming Li's Homepage http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/learning.html or Paul Vitaniy's homepage http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/learning.html.In fact,the articles are the same.

Somehow,it is slow when you run the program of it ,and it is just a approximate algorithm since Kolmogorov complexit is non computable.Actually,it is a univesal distance,which is  the best among all computable distance.